# Finding the item in selecteditemchanging event

Tags: asp.net

In listview im showing product information .On each row there is one select button on each row in itemTemplate .

if user click this button i want which  bookid is clicked in selectedindexchanging event.

i bound listview like following

```
  string str = "SELECT BookName,BookPrice, Description, bookid  FROM productinfo Where Categoryid ='" + Request.QueryString["CategoryId"] + "'";




 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();



        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);

        lstvwShopItems.DataSource = dt;

        lstvwShopItems.DataBind();
```

Please give solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to get a certain column when selecting a row you need to fill the property `datakeynames` with the property of your choice.

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.datakeynames.aspx)

getting the value of the property:

```
void lstvwShopItems_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string value = lstvwShopItems.SelectedValue;
  }
```

don't forget to set the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` on your listview to this method in the codebehind..

Comment: i set datakeynames="bookid". please tell me how retrieve now.